# Can I create an Array with an Int64?

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I basically want to create an array (`Array.array(k + 1, 1)`) but because `k` is of type `Int64` (it has to be), I can't create the array (gives error), so I am trying to find a way to bypass that error. Any Ideas?

P.s the values of `k < 20000` but it has to be stored as `Int64.int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert to an integer with `Int64.toInt`:

```
val k: Int64.int = ...
val a = Array.array (Int64.toInt k + 1, 1)
```